# How to indicate the number of persons that will be attending an event

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english

I created a website for users to RSVP to a wedding. One of the questions they have to answer is to indicate how many persons will attend the wedding.

What is the correct wording for a question like this? Currently I have used the following:

- We will attend **with** __ (where __ is the blank they have to fill in, e.g. 2)

Is this **with** preposition the correct one to use? Or is there a better wording convention to ask this? (e.g. We will be attending with)

It sounds a little awkward to me.

**Edit:** Added a picture to show the intent of the RSVP website
[image: RSVP website]

Comment: In your example: replace 'we' with a number, drop 'with'.

Comment: The quantity of discrete things like people is "number" rather than "amount".

Comment: I think I would put on the invitation *RSVP with numbers attending by 14th June*.

Comment: @WS2 I added a picture to show how the RSVP process works: users will access the website and have to fill in the following fields. I need the number of attendees to be able to do validation on it.

Comment: But if I receive an invite, I cannot invite whomever I fancy to come with me. The present format gives me this impression.  Let's say I am married and have four children, presumably each of us  will have received an invitation, it doesn't mean that all four children have to attend the wedding/reception, I could make other arrangements. So perhaps the RSVP should really be asking: *Please confirm the number of people attending*. A drop menu should appear, a numbered list, wherein I fill the names of the attendees.

Comment: There will be one invitation per family, and also one entry that will be submitted per family. For us, when we determine that maximum amount, we take into account whether they can bring children or not, but for us, the names of the attendees are not important, only the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides being clunky, that phrasing is also highly ambiguous.  Does "2" mean two people will be attending or that two additional people beyond whoever is filling in the form?

If it's just a blank some people might not even get that the blank is supposed to be a number.  You might get answers like "Fred" because they will be bringing Fred along with them.

There's also a slightly annoying aspect to the plural when the responder might well be attending alone.

If you want to avoid these problems, you might consider a plain, ordinary form with labelled entries rather than trying to fit it into running text.  It's

> Number of attendees:  _______
>
> Size of party: _______
>
> Size of group: _______
>
> Number of guests:  _______ (This one is questionable as it again could be interpreted as how many guests the responders will bring in addition to themselves)

It's boring but boring is better than misunderstanding.

For an unambiguous phrasing if you are set on the running text, you might try something like this:

> Our party will consist of _____ people.

Comment: Great feedback, thanks. I'm afraid I will have to go for the "boring" approach.
However, I prefill the number of attendees with the maximum allowed number of attendees, plus it also only allows numeric input.